# Parse string including brackets in R to dynamically construct condition expression for subsetting a data frame

Tags: r, subset

I have a string in R looking something like this:

```
s <- "[['column_i']]=='value_i' & [['column_j']]=='value_j' & [['column_k']]=='value_k'"
```

which I want to turn into an expression that can be used as a condition to subset a given data frame. The data frame has many more columns and the strings will be constructed dynamically and can have different number of columns.

I tried

```
parse(text=s)
```

but that gives me the error message "unexpected '[['".

Is there a way to include reserved special symbols like brackets in text that is to be parsed correctly?

Comment: The `[[` function requires an object to subset. You can't just have `[[a]]`, you need an object to subset: `x[[a]]`. What exactly is your input? How/why did you create that string? There may be a better, more R-like way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have a data frame with > 20 columns and about 3000 rows. I want to get the ratios between a large number of subsets defined by varying conditions and the whole data frame to construct conditional probability tables for a bayesian network constructed with gRain.

Comment: Maybe dplyr or data.table can help you with that. I agree with @MrFlick, there are more R-like ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into dplyr! The hint from MrFlick about having to include the data frame itself at the first position in the string to be able to parse it worked perfectly, too, though! But since it was a comment and not an answer I can't mark it as "accepted", can I?